# How to export Excel (CSV) data to HTML table with data-title and data-type

Tags: html, excel, csv, datatable, html-table

I have this huge list of sport players (833) in a CSV file, with their name, team name, and stats.

I created a table that is responsive like this:

```
<table class="responsive-table" id="my-table">
    <caption>AUDL Historical Stats</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Team</th>
        <th scope="col">Plus/ Minus</th>
        <th scope="col">Completions</th>
        <th scope="col">Attempts</th>
        <th scope="col">Comp %</th>
        <th scope="col">Assists</th>
        <th scope="col">Goals</th>
        <th scope="col">Scores (G+A)</th>
        <th scope="col">Drops</th>
        <th scope="col">Blocks</th>
        <th scope="col">Hockey Assists</th>
        <th scope="col">Points Played</th>
        <th scope="col">Games Played</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

/* PLAYER ONE */

<tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td data-title="Team"></td>
        <td data-title="Plus/ Minus" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Completions" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Attempts" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Comp %" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Assists" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Goals" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Scores (G+A)" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Drops" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Blocks" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Hockey Assists" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Points Played" data-type="double"></td>
        <td data-title="Games Played" data-type="double"></td>
      </tr>

/* PLAYER TWO */

...

</tbody>
  </table>
```

Instead of Copy and pasting the data one at a time. Is there a way to export with adding the "data-title" and "data-type" to the td tags, and scope="row" to the th tag for each player?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could use VBA in Excel for this, or any other programming language you know.

Comment: A mail merge into a single word document comes to mind as a low hanging fruit.